# Mysql Order by issue in WHERE IN function

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM (`poll`) WHERE `poll_id` IN ('6,10,5,9,1') AND `poll_status` = '1'
```

I tried this query. I expected It would give result as I gave. But It sorting the result automatically in ascending. I need result as I give. Kindly give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove single quote from IN parameter. Like `SELECT * FROM (poll) WHERE poll_id IN (6,10,5,9,1) AND poll_status = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FIELD` in mysql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`poll`) 
WHERE `poll_id` IN (6,10,5,9,1) 
  AND `poll_status` = 1
ORDER BY FIELD(`poll_id`,6,10,5,9,1)
```

Comment: @ Raging Bull Thank you For your comment. It is working well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your `id`s like that:

```
SELECT * FROM (`poll`) WHERE `poll_id` IN (6,10,5,9,1) AND `poll_status` = '1'
```